# F# Type inference with curried functions

Tags: types, f#, type-inference

I have the following code

```
let bar foo baz = foo, baz 

let z = bar 3
let z1 = z 2
```

however If I comment out the last line `let z1 = z 2` I get an error

```
let z = bar 3
----^

stdin(78,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. 
The value 'z' has been inferred to have generic type
val z : ('_a -> int * '_a)    
Either make the arguments to 'z' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, 
add a type annotation.
```

I am completely lost on how the annotate the function correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are facing here is an aspect of F# called *value restriction*. This essentially means that if you define a value that is not syntactically a function, then it cannot be generic.

```
let bar foo baz = foo, baz
```

... is syntactically a function (it obviously has two arguments) and so it is inferred as generic. However:

```
let z = bar 3
```

... is not syntactically a function - it is just a value `z` that happens to be a function (because that's what the type of `bar` indicates). So, this cannot be generic. In your snippet, the genericity was restricted by the next line:

```
let z1 = z 2
```

This fixes the type of `z` to be `int -> int * int`. If you don't have this line, you can fix the type yourself:

```
let z : int -> int * int = bar 3
```

Or, you can make this a syntactic function which can be inferred as generic:

```
let z a = bar 3 a
```

For more information, search the various other SO questions and answers that discuss [value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+value+restriction).